# How do I drop the a central column in a 3d array based on a condition?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

Given a 3d array:

```
a = np.array(
        [[[-1., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 1., -1., 1., 0., 0., -1., 1.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 1., -1., -1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 0., -1., 1., 7., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 8., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 3., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 4., 0., 0., 0.]],

          [[1., 0., -1., 0., -1., 1., -1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1., 1.],
           [1., 0., -1., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., -1., 4., 1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., -1., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., -1., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 0., 0., 1., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 6., 0., 0., 0.]],

          [[0., -1., 1., 0., -1., 1., 0., -1., 0., 1., 0., 0., -1., 1.],
           [0., -1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., -1., 0., -1., 4., 1., 0., 0.],
           [0., -1., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., -1., 0., 1., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., -1., 0., -1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 0., 1., 5., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 7., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

I want to drop the places where the 9th "column" is not -1
The result would look like this:

```
a = np.array(
    [[[0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 1., -1., -1., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 8., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 4., 0., 0., 0.]],

      [[1., 0., -1., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., -1., 4., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., -1., 0., 0., -1., 2., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 6., 0., 0., 0.]],

      [[0., -1., 1., 0., 0., 1., 0., -1., 0., -1., 4., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0., -1., 0., -1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1., 7., 0., 0., 0.]]])
```

context: These are histories of 3 tictactoe games. The dimensions are like this:

a.shape = (game number, historical state, state property)

So I am trying to gather all the games of player -1's turn.

Comment: Sorry - I meant index 9 which is the same as column 10

Comment: so a[:,:,9] are the values I would like to use for the mask

Comment: I understood. I've erased my comment. It's all clear now.

Comment: mask = a[range(len(a)),:,9]==-1       b = a[range(len(a))][mask] works to gather all the right rows, but it kinda just bunches them all together which isn't right either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used your suggestion for slicing

```
player = a[:,:,9]
wanted != 1
wanted = wanted[:3] #three games

games = np.array(np.array_split(a[wanted],3))

print(games)

[[[ 0.  0.  0.  1. -1.  0.  0.  1. -1. -1.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  1. -1.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  8.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  4.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 1.  0. -1.  0.  0.  1. -1.  0.  0. -1.  4.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1. -1.  0.  0. -1.  2.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  6.  0.  0.  0.]]

[[ 0. -1.  1.  0.  0.  1.  0. -1.  0. -1.  4.  1.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  1.  0. -1.  0. -1.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
[ 0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0.  0. -1.  7.  0.  0.  0.]]]
```